# Remove duplicates from results in SQL on JOINS

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I want to make a query where it will not pick up both the AAA BBB values from table 2. Anytime I run a query with the JOIN (I tried all the different joins) it will give me duplicate values in the result (001 - AAA and 001 - BBB). The resulting query should only have the 3 values AAA CCC DDD. Is this even possible ?

```
SELECT *, ST_AsGeoJSON(geom,5) AS geojson  FROM table1  
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table.id2=table2.id2
GROUP BY table.id2
```

I tried the above query but it errors out. column "table2.Id2" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

```
table 1

    id  test        

    001  |  A
    002  |  B
    003  |  C
    007  |  D

table2
id2(fk)  test2      

001    |  AAA
001    |  BBB
003    |  CCC
007    |  DDD
```

I'm fairly new to SQL so I apologize.
Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks!

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: I got it to work with SELECT DISTINCT. Is there any other way of doing this ?

Comment: There may be, but it is unclear what you actually want.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Stop trying to code your overall goal & explain what you expected instead from the given code & why.

Comment: Your error message is a faq. Before considering posting please read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. PS Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, you are getting error because you have not included `table2.id2` in your `group by`.

```
SELECT *, 
    ST_AsGeoJSON(geom,5) AS geojson  
FROM table1  t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.id2=t2.id2
GROUP BY 
 t1.id2,
 t2.id2
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `GROUP BY` at all.  You have no aggregation functions:

```
SELECT *, ST_AsGeoJSON(geom, 5) AS geojson 
FROM table1 LEFT JOIN
     table2
     ON table1.id2 = table2.id2;
```

If you want one row per `id2`, you can use `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (table1.id2) *, ST_AsGeoJSON(geom, 5) AS geojson 
FROM table1 LEFT JOIN
     table2
     ON table1.id2 = table2.id2
ORDER BY table1.id2;
```

Note:  This will return an *arbitrary* matching row when there are duplicates.  If you want a *particular* value, then add a second key to `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Hmm now it seems that I can't ORDER BY now though.
SELECT DISTINCT ON (eats2.id2) id2, * 
FROM eats2 LEFT JOIN 
 eats2_imgs ON eats2.id2=eats2_imgs.id2_eats2;
ORDER BY eats2.id2 
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ORDER"

Comment: I got it to work like this. 
SELECT DISTINCT ON (eats2.id2,eats2.score) * 
FROM eats2 LEFT JOIN eats2_imgs ON eats2.id2=eats2_imgs.id2_eats2
ORDER BY eats2.score DESC
Thanks man!